# Can I change the page background for cache hit vs. miss?

Tags: caching, varnish

I have a page cache running (Varnish) and the VCL sets the X-Cache header to HIT or MISS when it delivers the page. While I'm debugging, I get tired of finding the page headers in my browser to see if the page was a hit or miss; I would like to have the page background (or border) change.

Varnish won't let me modify the body, just the headers and cookies.

I could change the VCL to set a cookie, and then implement some Javascript in a plugin to check the cookie and change the background... yet I feel there must be a more elegant way to do this.

Has anybody done this sort of thing before, and how did it work out?

Comment: How is it specific to wordpress?

Comment: I asked in WordPress because I would prefer to implement this as a WordPress plugin, in a cache-agnostic manner. But it got migrated here... where I will figure out how to do it and implement it as a WordPress plugin.

Comment: To implement anything you first need to know what is it that needs to be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that somewhat more elegant way would be to send the styles using Link header. This will not involve sending the cookie or using Javascript.

But that would work with Firefox only:

```cpp
sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "cached";
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "uncached";
        set resp.http.Link = "</miss.css>;rel=stylesheet;type=text/css;media=all";
    }
}
```

Comment: Browser-specific would work for this situation. It is certainly the cleanest.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to experience 'race conditions' with the cookie approach because that state is shared among all tabs browsing the site. The best approach would be:

1. Store a `hit` / `miss` flag in `req.http.whatever`.
2. Include a ESI fragment in all your pages (e.g. `/color-hack.html`).
3. Add VCL logic to catch `/color-hack.html` requests during `vcl_recv`, jump to `vcl_synth`, and generate some HTML or JavaScript depending on the value of the flag in `req_top.http.whatever`. Then you can use that in the client side to change the color of the pace of whatever you want to do.

I know it looks a little bit convoluted, but it should be simple to implement if you are familiar with ESI & synthetic responses.